# How to map from MongoDB to a domain Model

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, domain-driven-design, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public class RecommenderQuery
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string RoleIds { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string QueryType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
public class Audience : AudienceInstance
{
    public RecommenderQuery RecommenderQuery { get; set; }
    public virtual string RecommenderId { get; set; }
    public Guid ResultId { get; set; }
    public int? Rank { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

These are the domain model I have.
[image]

This is the data I have in Mongo db.

I want to map those data to my domain model without creating an MDO for this.
But MongoDB driver mapping fails, as it tries to map ,
for eg: When it tries to map ArticleId, it tries to find it in Audience. But its actually inside Audience.RecommenderQuery. So it fails.
Is there a way to overcome this without additional model?

```
var builder = Builders<Audience>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.And(builder.Where(x => x.ArticleId == articleId
                                               && x.RecommenderQuery.RoleIds == roleIds));
        var projection = Builders<Audience>.Projection.Include(x => x.Id)
                                                                .Include(x => x.ArticleId)
                                                                .Include(x => x.RecommenderQuery.IsActive)
                                                                .Include(x => x.RecommenderQuery.CreatedDate)
                                                                .Include(x => x.RecommenderQuery.QueryType)
                                                                .Include(x => x.RecommenderQuery.Status);
        var recommendQueries = await Database.GetCollection<Audience>(collectionName).Find(filter).Project<Audience>(projection).ToListAsync();
```

This is where the mapping happens.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance